# How to append search string to URL?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url

I am doing a project in Angular JS. There I have one HTML file which has one link. That link takes user to another page and that page has status of **all the components** of my application.

Now I want to modify that link so that it shows me status of **one specific component** whose name is "**Deployment-manager**". For that I need to apply a search string in URL.

This is my current URL:

```
http://10.0.1.189:5601/#/dashboard/Default?_g=()&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:7,columns:!
(host,path,message),id:yarn,row:6,size_x:6,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),
type:search),(col:1,columns:!(host,path,message),id:kafka,row:6,size_x:6,size_y:3,
sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc)",type:search),(col:1,columns:!(host,path,message),id:minion,row:9,size_x:12,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),
type:search),(col:1,id:All-log-types-over-time,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:1,columns:!
(host,path,message,source),id:all,row:3,size_x:12,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),type:search)),
query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:%27*%27)),title:Default)
```

If you see this link carefully , you will "Query" string in that link's last line. There I need to put that specific component name. Something like below URL:

http://10.0.1.189:5601/#/dashboard/Default?_g=()&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:7,columns:!(host,path,message),id:yarn,row:6,size_x:6,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),type:search),(col:1,columns:!(host,path,message),id:kafka,row:6,size_x:6,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),type:search),(col:1,columns:!(host,path,message),id:minion,row:9,size_x:12,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),type:search),(col:1,id:All-log-types-over-time,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:1,columns:!(host,path,message,source),id:all,row:3,size_x:12,size_y:3,sort:!(%27@timestamp%27,desc),type:search)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:deployment-manager)),title:Default)

In the above URL , I have put that specific component name i.e "Deployment-manager" in query string. How can I append this in HTML or AngularJS or Javascript.

Below is my HTML code which has link:

```
<p>Please follow <a target="_blank" href="{{link}}" class="tooltip-test" data-title="{{link}}" bs-tooltip>this</a> link to fix issues related to {{componentName}}.</p>
"
```

This link's {{link}} value is coming from my Angular Js controller . And controller is sending this link's value is this only http://10.0.1.189:5601
But it gets translated to a big URL which I mentioned above.

So I need to append this query parameter into my URL. How can I do so?

Comment: you must be redirecting this url to the given above which are getting in your app module file check where you are defining for page redirection code

Answer (score 0):

You can use $location service, `$location.url(url).search(search);`